# Extracting an hour by hour shadow price in an MIP using Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to extract the shadow price for a particular constraint within my MIP model - and am using Gurobi as the solver.

When I am establishing the constraint, I use the following code -

`# Balance Constraint
for hour in hours:
    model.addConstr((quicksum(p[hour, i] for i in num_gen) + 
    (quicksum(discharge[hour, i] for i in num_gen)) == demand[hour] + 
     quicksum(charge[hour, i] for i in num_gen)), name="balance")`

Then, having solved the MIP, and optimised the fixed version of the MIP, I use the following code to extract the dual value for the demand constraint.

```
demand_constr = fixed.getConstrByName("balance")
```

However, the above only returns a single value, where as I was expecting a shadow price for every hour for which this constraint was applied.

Perhaps this is a misunderstanding of mine - but if anyone can assist it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you call Model.addConstr(), save the Constr object.  Better yet, try Model.addConstrs(), which returns a Python dictionary of the constraints.